# Eclipse Maven Rest Api: error : UserNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Here is the full code. It's throwing an error at UserNotFoundException.

```
@RestController
public class UserResource {
    
    //GET /users/{id}
    //retrieveUser(int id)
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User retrieveUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = service.findone(id);
        if(user==null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException("id-"+ id); //this throwing the error.
        return user;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `UserNotFoundException` sounds like an Exception you defined on your own. So I guess you have to import it.

Comment: Thx. @Jasmeet let me selfish and post it as an answer to score ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`UserNotFoundException` sounds like an Exception you defined on your own. So I guess you have to import it:

```
import yourpackage.UserNotFoundException
```